# В чем разница между bintime() и nanotime()?

Tags: freebsd, kernel

В чем разница между `nanotime(9)` и `bintime(9)`, если возвращаемое значение `bintime(struct bintime)` можно конвертировать c помощью `bintime2timespec` в значение `nanotime(timespec)`?

Comment: Здесь http://phk.freebsd.dk/pubs/timecounter.pdf PHK объясняет, зачем во FreeBSD 5.0 ввели семейство функций времени bin* с 1/2^64 долями секунды

Comment: К сожалению не смог осилить на английском поэтому и задал вопрос (находил уже этот документ). Буду благодарен за разжеванный ответ на русском.

Comment: @Axeleratortt не нужно откатывать к первой ревизии - это чистой воды вандализм.

Comment: @Regent не вижу смысла вносить какие либо правки в маленький вопрос.

Comment: @Axeleratortt если правки улучшают вид сообщения, то в них есть смысл. В конце концов, вас же не заставляют вносить правки - нужно только не "ломать" сделанное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bintime` использует структуры с более натуральными полями, арифметика над которыми значительно проще, и потому их использование более эффетивно. Текущие версии ядра и системных утилит используют именно `bintime` структуры для операций с отметками времени, переводя в други форматы только при необходимости. Грубо говоря, `nanotime` реализовано через `bintime`.

Comment: void
nanotime(struct timespec *tsp)
{
 struct bintime bt;

 bintime(&bt);
 bintime2timespec(&bt, tsp);
}

Да вы правы. Тут даже не грубо говоря, а так и есть.